# How to update statistics automatically in Sybase ASE 15.7

Tags: relational-database, sybase, sap-ase

I want to update the statistics for all the tables in Sybase ASE 15.7
My question is if there is an automatic way to do it especially when there is no running process esp. at night?

Thanks,

Ali

Comment: It would be helpful to know which OS you are referring to, as that can affect how you can set up reoccurring jobs.

Comment: Our server is on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 5.5 (Tikanga) and the Linux Kernel version is 2.6.18-194.e15 x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Sybase ASE Job Scheduler](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20001.1570/html/jsusers/title.htm) to setup tasks to run on a regular basis.

> Job Scheduler eases the management of ASE by providing the ability to define and schedule database administration and maintenance tasks. With Job Scheduler, jobs that normally require interaction from a database administrator can be scheduled to run unattended at the appropriate times, freeing the database administrator to attend to other issues.
>
> Job Scheduler allows you to create and schedule jobs, and to share jobs and schedules. One database administrator can create a job, and other database administrators can then schedule and run that job on another server. You can create jobs as follows:
>
> - From scratch using the command line or GUI
> - From a SQL batch file
> - From a template
>
> Job Scheduler captures the results and output of jobs and records that information in log tables. This data can be viewed at a later date. In addition, Job Scheduler keeps a history of scheduled jobs; however, to keep a limit on the size of the history table, Job Scheduler monitors it and removes outdated, unnecessary history records.

Comment: Sometimes, due to network problems the "update all statistics" command would not work and the table will not be updated. How would I distinguish the tables which were not updated?

Comment: This should probably be it's own question, but I will look into it when I get a chance.